# 1036 Table 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql5598_2b_0.MAI' is read only

Tags: mysql

Below is my error, I have fixed the database is up to date but I still get this error. I also tried the similiar answers I got here but am not winning please assist because I don't know what to do now....

changing the permissions I couldn't because am using windows and the solution I got was to use `sudo` also tried to repair the database but throws `not storage engine not supported`

Errors:

> lepopoo.yq05v_action_logs --repair--note---The storage engine for the table doesn't support r...
>
> 1036 Table 'C:\xampp\tmp#sql5598_2b_0.MAI' is read only

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using ? `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Also the `.MAI` extension sounds like you are using MariaDB, which is a source code fork off MySQL..

Comment: MySQL Version 10.1.38-MariaDB
PHP Version 7.3.4